# Full-text search across concatenated columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm new to free-text search, so pardon the newbie question. Suppose I have the following full-text index:

```
Create FullText Index on Contacts(
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Organization
)
Key Index PK_Contacts_ContactID
Go
```

I want to do a freetext search against all three columns concatenated

```
FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Organization
```

So that for example

- Searching for `jim smith` returns all contacts named Jim Smith
- Searching for `smith ibm` returns all contacts named Smith who work at IBM

This seems like it would be a fairly common scenario. I would have expected this to work:

```
Select c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Organization, ft.Rank
from FreeTextTable(Contacts, *, 'smith ibm') ft
Left Join Contacts c on ft.[Key]=c.ContactID
Order by ft.Rank Desc
```

but this is apparently doing `smith OR ibm`; it returns a lot of Smiths who don't work at IBM and vice versa. Surprisingly, searching for `smith AND ibm` yields identical results.

This does what I want...

```
Select c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Organization
from Contacts c 
where Contains(*, 'smith') and Contains(*, 'ibm')
```

...but then I can't parameterize queries coming from the user -- I would have to break up the search string into words myself and assemble the SQL on the fly, which is ugly and unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach I take is to create a search view or calculated column (using a trigger) that puts all of those values into a single field.

The other thing I do is to use a full-text search engine- such as Lucene/Solr.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using the calculated column/trigger approach to populate a SearchText field, and indexing that.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean operators are only supported for CONTAINS, not FREETEXT.

Try your AND query with CONTAINSTABLE.

Comment: If I replace FREETEXTTABLE with CONTAINSTABLE, it returns no results. I assume that's because there's no one column that contains both "smith" and "ibm" - "smith" is in LastName and "ibm" is in Organization.