# SQL CONTAINS or FREETEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im trying to use either CONTAINS or FREETEXT in SQL programing to be able to search couple words all at the same time. The issue is when you search couple words FREETEXT or CONTAINS will search by column not by row for example:
Imagine this is my database

```
id        | c1      | c2 
===============================
a         | 1       | 2     
b         | 1       | 3     
c         | 1       | 2     
d         | 2       | 2     
e         | 3       | 3     
f         | 2       | 1
```

When you search `CONTAINS(*, '1,2')` OR off curse `FREETEXT(*, '1 2')` it will return

```
id        | c1      | c2 
===============================
a         | 1       | 2     
b         | 1       | 3     
c         | 1       | 1     
d         | 2       | 2     
e         | 2       | 3     
f         | 2       | 1
```

Which is basically entire database. But what I wanted was this

```
id        | c1      | c2 
===============================
a         | 1       | 2     
f         | 2       | 1
```

Which is the rows that contains 1 and 2 combine.

By the way I'm using SQL 2008 and ASP classic.

I would really appreciate for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem often. The solution I have used has never really satisfied me performance wise, but it does work. It is CONCATENATING the values I am searching for.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT (T.C1 + '-' + T.C2) AS C3, *
    FROM TABLE T
    WHERE T.C1 IN (ALL VALUES FOR C1)
) T2
WHERE T2.C3 IN (ALL CONCATENATED VALUES)
```

IF TYPES ARE NUMERIC, YOU SHOULD USE CONVERT OR CAST TO VARCHAR.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I got an error using contains for lack of indexing. Change to IN.

Comment: Thans for suggestion but I got this error "Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'C3' because it is not full-text indexed." which my table is already full-text  indexed

Comment: @Jay -I know, I got the same error after I posted. Look at my EDIT. Do you HAVE to use CONTAINS? or is it just preferable?

Comment: The way I constructed the Stored Procedures, yes I have to use CONTAINS or FREETEXT.

Comment: Check the suggestion on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820215/full-text-search-across-concatenated-columns